# pass data between two unrelated vue.js component when user click on image

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to make confirmation dialogue.

My project has too many places where confirmation is required the flow is same in all cases

```
user click on some button ---> get confirmation ---> execute request of user
```

for example:
there is a upcomingsC.vue component which has image
confirmation box must be seen every time user clicks on image

```
<template>
    <div ref="cfm" id="confirm-dia" class="hide" v-on:confirm="show(msg)">
        <p>do you really want to do this</p>
        <button class="positive" @click="hide">procced</button>
        <button class="negative" @click="hide">cancel</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "ConfirmationC",
        props: {
            msg : String,
        },
        methods:{
            show(msg) {
                console.log("working",msg)
                this.$refs.cfm.classList.add('show')
            },
            hide() {
                this.$refs.cfm.classList.remove('show')
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    #confirm-dia {
        width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color:antiquewhite;
        position: absolute;
        top:30%;
        right:30%;
        z-index: 99;
    }
    .show {
        display: block !important;
    }
    .hide {
        display: none 
    }
</style>
```

upcomingsC.vue

```
<tr class="upc-tr" v-for="(item,key) of getUpcomings" :key="key">
    <router-link :to="{name:'edit', path : '/u/upcoming/edit', params: {baserecord : JSON.stringify(item)}}">
       <img src="../assets/buttons/edit-upc.png" class="edit-upc" alt="edit record">
    </router-link>
                           
    <ConfirmationC/>
    <img v-on:click="$emit('confirm','some')" src="../assets/buttons/delete-upc.png" class="del-upc mn-l-8"  alt="delete record">
</tr>
```

I want to use ComponentC.vue only once, pass details of which router-link's image is clicked as props (I will take care of defining and passing props)
I can not make changes in confirmationC.vue component

any help is apreciated .....

Comment: "I can not make changes in confirmationC.vue component"  what do you mean? why can you not modify the component?

Comment: As I said this confirmationC component will be used at too many place so I want to make it as much resuable as I can for that I will also introduce props `msg`, `fnToCallNext`,`fnArg`. I want to use events. Thats it. I will appreciate if you use event and don't introduce any hard coded stuff

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do and what the problem is. "pass data between two unrelated vue.js component" - which components? There should be no place for a guesswork Please, be more specific, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: if you use a store like Vuex or [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/introduction.html) you can bind the display of your component to a store value that other components can turn on/off without needing to emit anything.  you also need to utilize [v-if](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html)` in your component to control the display which you would bind to your store value.  using refs to add/remove classes for controlling display is an outdated and cumbersome strategy.  you need to read through the Vue documentation to understand the framework's true potential

Comment: I am already using vuex in this project. @Estus Flask just want to know if I can send an event to confirmationC.vue when I click on delete-upc.png image in upcoming sc.vue

Comment: Use hide() on confirmation's ref. Btw the use of classList in Vue is almost always unwanted, this is done with class bindings

Comment: @Estus Flask then how would I pass the props ?

Comment: You can pass props as you need to ConfirmationC. Components are on the same level

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but it will be very helpful to me if I can get a look on improved code. Is it possible for you to share it ?

Comment: I just figured out that I haven't shared the exact content of UpcomingsC.vue.  I have just edited the question Please take a look at it